# How do I connect my Samsung Galaxy S6 to Android Studio?

Tags: samsung, usb-drivers

I've downloaded a driver called SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_For_Mobile_Phones. When I plug in my phone via USB-MicroUSB, the phones begins charging, but is not recognized by the computer. How do I get my computer to recognize the device, and how do I then connect it to Android Studio? I would really appreciate any assistance at all. Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure that your USB cable supports data transfer.
- Did you turned on 'Developer mode'?!
  Settings > About Phone > scroll to the bottom > tap Build number seven (7) times.

Comment: Yes I turned on Developer Mode. I didn't know that some USB cables didn't support that...I guess I will look around the house for another one!

Comment: Found one, and yup. It was just the cable. Thanks!